# Bootstrap typeahead, change the datasource used by the bloodhound suggestion engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, typeahead

I've a search field with autocomplete that is initialized like this:

```
    var reposVenda = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.bairro); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: urlAutoCompleteVenda
    }
});

var reposAluguel = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.bairro); },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: urlAutoCompleteAluguel
    }
});

reposVenda.initialize();
reposAluguel.initialize();

$('#searchQuery').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'bairros',
    displayKey: 'bairro',
    source: reposVenda.ttAdapter(),
    templates: {
        suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
          '<p class="bairro-autocomplete">{{bairro}}</p>'
        ].join(''))
    },
    queryTokenizer: queryTokenizer
});
```

Now I need to change the source when user clicks a button on the page:

```
    $(".opt-busca-home").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var idItem = $(this).attr("id");
    buscaAtual = idItem.replace("opt-", "");

    if (buscaAtual == "comprar") {
        var autocomplete = $('#searchQuery').typeahead();
        autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = reposVenda.ttAdapter();
    }
    else {
        var autocomplete = $('#searchQuery').typeahead();
        autocomplete.data('typeahead').source = reposAluguel.ttAdapter();
    }
});
```

The problem is when I click the button to change the source the console tells me  'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'source' of undefined'

I tried every possible approach without success. The typeahead works but only with the initialized source. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I used the destroy/recreate typeahead approach because I thouhgt it was easier to implement.

Comment: The destroy/recreate approach isn't really easier to implement. Just compare the code in the answers. Also the bloodhound clear and re-initialize methods were written to do exactly what they say, so there isnt a need to destroy and recreate. Anyhow, glad you've got a solution which works for you.

Comment: I don't think that your approach was easier since I need to clear all the cache and then do another requisition to server to get the new list. Destroy only the typeahead and let the bloodhound alone IMHO was more friendly for what I needed.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes my approach would trigger a refetch. I'll leave my answer as it will be a good approach if using a local or remote data source.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a way of switching between data sources here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/EEuyL/

Note that whilst I've used local data sources in my answer, the solution will also be valid for prefetch/remote sources.

The code which I'm using to toggle between the different data sources is here:

```
var sourceSelected = $('#sourceSelected');
var toggle = false;

$('#switch').click(function () {
    titles.clear(); // First remove all suggestions from the search index

    if (!toggle) {
        toggle = true;
        titles.local = data2; // Next choose the desired alternate data source
        sourceSelected.text('Data Source 2');
    } else {
        toggle = false;
        titles.local = data1;
        sourceSelected.text('Data Source 1');
    }

    // Finally reinitialise the bloodhound suggestion engine
    titles.initialize(true); 
});
```

You can find the documentation for Bloodhound's clear method [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#bloodhoundclear), and its reinitialize method [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#bloodhoundinitializereinitialize).

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do it will be to destroy the `typeahead` control and re-initialize it:

```
$(".opt-busca-home").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#searchQuery').typeahead('destroy');

    var idItem = $(this).attr("id");
    buscaAtual = idItem.replace("opt-", "");

    var source = null;
    if (buscaAtual == "comprar") {
        source = reposVenda.ttAdapter();
    }
    else {
        source = reposAluguel.ttAdapter();
    }

    $('#searchQuery').typeahead(null, {
        name: 'bairros',
        displayKey: 'bairro',
        source: source,
        templates: {
            suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
              '<p class="bairro-autocomplete">{{bairro}}</p>'
            ].join(''))
        },
        queryTokenizer: queryTokenizer
    });
});
```

Comment: Why destroy and re-create when functions exists to clear and re-initialize the data source?